# PHP5.3 hangs IIS6 on windows2003 64bit

Tags: php, iis-6, 64-bit, windows-server-2003

I am setting up php 64bit on IIS6 (windows 2k3 ).

The need is I want my existing website(classic asp) to include a wordpress blog (mu) with friendly url. So want to install it as a subdirectory to the IIS website. I have single IP allocated. Could not get the 32 bit php environment working as per [IISADMIN](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=14)

Upon setting up for 64bit php settings my IIS websites hangs indefinitely. No event viewer logs so clueless.

Can the workaround be using url rewriting? I am avoiding this as I have to either upgrade to IIS7 or use mod_rewrite for Apache. I a not much confident with that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the thread-safe version of PHP5 for windows,  next set "[error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)" in PHP to a valid path, lastly enable [display_startup_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors).   After changing these, try running PHP5 from the command line like

```
#php -c c:/path/2/php.ini -r 'phpinfo();'
```

and verify it works correctly.

The Thread safety is usually what does it, but it might be something else like a bad path, missing php.ini in its search path ( usually it goes ./php.exe and then c:\windows\php.ini )